# Airflow is not triggering dags even after they have been manually triggered from the UI due to dagbag errors

Tags: python, airflow

### Airflow is loading all the dags into the db but is not triggering them.

### The log files are showing the following errors

```
[2020-01-05 02:55:06,226] {{dagbag.py:436}}   
[2020-01-05 02:55:02,610] {{dagbag.py:403}}
INFO - Filling up the DagBag   
from /usr/local/airflow/dags [2020-01-05 02:55:06,226] {{dagbag.py:436}}  
ERROR - [Errno 22] Invalid argument Traceback (most recent call last):   File"/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/sitepackages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", 
line 420, in collect_dags safe_mode=safe_mode) 
File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 251, in  
process_file zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(filepath) 
File  "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1131,   in init 
self
_RealGetContents() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py",  line 
1216 in _RealGetContents fp.seek(self.start_dir, 0 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Could you post the function being trigged in `dagbag.py:436` along with the arguments that you are passing into the function.

Comment: Thank you Philip for answering. There are no arguments being passed from me directly. Airflow picks up the dags from the db (postgres tables) and executes them when triggered by the user(myself) or via a schedule (defined within the dag). So part of the process is working Airflow is picking the dags and inserting into the db but on execution trigger is throwing up the error above. I have tried upgrading airflow to the latest version as well python version since this seems like a python execution error. I am going to try and format my original question as well so its more readable.

Comment: @SanjayM what version of Airflow do you have installed? Also do you get the same error when you run this from the terminal?

`python -c 'from airflow.models import DagBag; d = DagBag();'`

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question. The log file errors remain however the dags are now getting triggered successfully. The problem was the dags needed to be made active(switched on) and not simply triggered to run